# Twitter integration in ios app without account setup in device

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter

I want to integration twitter in my application without Account setup in my phone is it possible? and how that possible please explain me.

Comment: https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGTwitterEngine

Comment: Try fabric.io for twitter integration.

Comment: @Bhavuk Jain are you ever use fabric.io for twitter integration?

Comment: Haven't tried it yet. But there are code examples you should check out. https://fabric.io/kits/ios/twitterkit/features